# CreateML error dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCreateML.dylib

Tags: swift, dyld, createml

I have been trying to create a model but the code seems to fail at the instantiation of the very first MLDataTable object with an error code I cannot figure out how to resolve.

Error report:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCreateML.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/ritwikpimac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Billions-epqozturxqfhiwcinwrbmmhqavnj/Build/Products/Debug/Billions.app/Contents/MacOS/Billions
  Reason: image not found
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also ran in to this issue on a project that had been running and using this library without issue for months. Here is what worked for me:

Select your target, and under the "**General**" tab go to "**Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content**" (see the screenshot below). Here you can add "**libSwiftCreateML.dylib**".

[image: Screenshot]